# adding custom text instead of number for jquery slider ResponsiveSlides.js v1.53

Tags: jquery

Im trying to add a custom text to each slide instead of using the bullet points. im trying to assign the style to the name.

I am using ResponsiveSlides.js v1.53 https://github.com/viljamis/ResponsiveSlides.js/blob/master/README.md

Here is the slider and the pager that comes in the function any ideas?

and the script:

```
<script>
 $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
  auto: true,             // Boolean: Animate automatically, true or false
  speed: 500,            // Integer: Speed of the transition, in milliseconds
  timeout: 4000,          // Integer: Time between slide transitions, in milliseconds
  pager: true,           // Boolean: Show pager, true or false
  nav: false,             // Boolean: Show navigation, true or false
  random: false,          // Boolean: Randomize the order of the slides, true or false
  pause: true,           // Boolean: Pause on hover, true or false
  pauseControls: true,    // Boolean: Pause when hovering controls, true or false
  prevText: "Previous",   // String: Text for the "previous" button
  nextText: "Next",       // String: Text for the "next" button
  maxwidth: "",           // Integer: Max-width of the slideshow, in pixels
  navContainer: "",       // Selector: Where controls should be appended to, default is after the 'ul'
  manualControls: "",     // Selector: Declare custom pager navigation
  namespace: "rslides",   // String: Change the default namespace used
  before: function(){},   // Function: Before callback
  after: function(){}     // Function: After callback
});
</script>
```

my site im working on you will notice the pager underneath the slider. forget the ACF error.

http://mrblind.dev/aluminium-blinds/

Answer (score 0):

Each number is inside .rslides_tab class and has anchor tags with classes that start with rslides1_. So you can use .each() to change text for all numbers like:

```
var i=0;
var arr = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ];
$(".rslides_tabs a[class^='rslides1_']").each(function(){
 $(this).text(arr[i]);
 i++;
});
```